# How can I have a python function that effectively divide a list to all possible number of chunks?

Tags: python-3.x, chunks

I want to split a list (float or integer) according to the following conditions:

- Splitting the list into all possible subsamples.
- No duplication.
- A unit sample cannot be a subsample.

I have what splits a list into equal sizes by giving the number of subsamples.

**The code I have laid my hand on which worked but does not give me what I want**

```
import numpy as np
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
l = np.array_split(x,3)
```

**output**

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10]]
```

I desire to have a list of subsample of all possibilities without duplication. that is, a combination of all unique possibilities when the list is split into 2, 3, 4, etc (no two or more subsamples will have the same element)).

I do not what to specify chunk number so that it will not be limited to such number.

**Here is what I did manually**

From the following series [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] I sliced it into all possible blocks as follows:

**when splitting into 2**

```
[1][2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
[1,2][3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
[1,2,3][4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
[1,2,3,4][5,6,7,8,9,10]
[1,2,3,4,5][6,7,8,9,10]
[1,2,3,4,5,6][7,8,9,10]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8][9,10]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9][10]
```

**when splitting into 3**

```
[1][2][3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
[1][2,3][4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
[1][2,3,4][5,6,7,8,9,10]
[1][2,3,4,5][6,7,8,9,10]
[1][2,3,4,5,6][7,8,9,10]
[1][2,3,4,5,6,7][8,9,10]
[1][2,3,4,5,6,7,8][9,10]
[1][2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9][10]

[1,2][3][4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
[1,2][3,4][5,6,7,8,9,10]
[1,2][3,4,5][6,7,8,9,10]
[1,2][3,4,5,6][7,8,9,10]
[1,2][3,4,5,6,7][8,9,10]
[1,2][3,4,5,6,7,8][9,10]
[1,2][3,4,5,6,7,8,9][10]

[1,2,3][4][5,6,7,8,9,10]
[1,2,3][4,5][6,7,8,9,10]
[1,2,3][4,5,6][7,8,9,10]
[1,2,3][4,5,6,7][8,9,10]
[1,2,3][4,5,6,7,8][9,10]
[1,2,3][4,5,6,7,8,9][10]

[1,2,3,4][5][6,7,8,9,10]
[1,2,3,4][5,6][7,8,9,10]
[1,2,3,4][5,6,7][8,9,10]
[1,2,3,4][5,6,7,8][9,10]
[1,2,3,4][5,6,7,8,9][10]

[1,2,3,4,5][6][7,8,9,10]
[1,2,3,4,5][6,7][8,9,10]
[1,2,3,4,5][6,7,8][9,10]
[1,2,3,4,5][6,7,8,9][10]

[1,2,3,4,5,6][7][8,9,10]
[1,2,3,4,5,6][7,8][9,10]
[1,2,3,4,5,6][7,8,9][10]
```

**when splitting into 4**

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7][8][9,10]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7][8,9][10]

[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8][9][10]
```

**After all possible splitting into blocks, I removed all the single digit blocks and also removed all duplicated blocks.**

```
[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]


[3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
[2,3]
[2,3,4]
[2,3,4,5]
[2,3,4,5,6]
[2,3,4,5,6,7]
[2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

[4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
[3,4]
[3,4,5]
[3,4,5,6]
[3,4,5,6,7]
[3,4,5,6,7,8]
[1,2][3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

[5,6,7,8,9,10]
[4,5]
[4,5,6]
[4,5,6,7]
[4,5,6,7,8]
[1,2,3][4,5,6,7,8,9]

[6,7,8,9,10]
[5,6]
[5,6,7]
[5,6,7,8]
[1,2,3,4][5,6,7,8,9]

[1,2,3,4,5][7,8,9,10]
[6,7]
[6,7,8]
[6,7,8,9]

[8,9,10]
[7,8]
[1,2,3,4,5,6][7,8,9]


[9,10]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7][8,9]

[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

**Here, I gather all the possible chunks together.**

This is what I desire as an output.

```
[[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], [2,3], [2,3,4], [2,3,4,5], [2,3,4,5,6], [2,3,4,5,6,7], [2,3,4,5,6,7,8], [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], [4,5,6,7,8,9,10],[3,4], [3,4,5], [3,4,5,6], [3,4,5,6,7], [3,4,5,6,7,8], [1,2], [3,4,5,6,7,8,9], [5,6,7,8,9,10], [4,5], [4,5,6], [4,5,6,7], [4,5,6,7,8], [1,2,3], [4,5,6,7,8,9], [6,7,8,9,10], [5,6], [5,6,7], [5,6,7,8], [1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8,9], [1,2,3,4,5], [7,8,9,10], [6,7], [6,7,8], [6,7,8,9], [8,9,10], [7,8], [1,2,3,4,5,6], [7,8,9], [9,10], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], [8,9], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]]
```

Comment: When splitting into 2, why is `[1,2,3,4][5,6,7,8,9,10]` not a solution?

Comment: It is not an absolute solution because we can have more than that. [1][2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9][10] are also possible but spliting into 3 will produce a dublication.

Comment: It is not an absolute solution because we can have more than that. [1][2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9][10] are also possible but spliting into 3 will produce a dublication. [1,2,3,4][5], [6,7,8,9,10],[1,2,3,4][5,6], [7,8,9,10],  [1,2,3,4][5,6,7][8,9,10], [1,2,3,4][5,6,7,8][9,10], [1,2,3,4][5,6,7,8,9][10] and [1][2,3,4][5,6,7,8,9,10], [1,2][3,4][5,6,7,8,9,10], [1,2,3][4][5,6,7,8,9,10]

Comment: Sorry, I do not get the rules by what you partition and weed out dupes. Good luck.

Comment: Look at `def powerset(..):...` in https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes  - this might hepl you create your needed partitions - if you start it for `range(2,len(s))` it should eliminate all 0 and 1 lenght parts

Comment: you are correct in observation, I have added all possible splits for 2 blocks in my question. Please do not weed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like the problem reduces to finding all substrings of length 2 or greater that leave at least one fragment of length 1. In other words, you won't have to enumerate every partition to find them.

```py
def parts(thing):
    result = []
    for i in range(len(thing)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(thing) + 1):
            if 1 < len(thing[i:j]) < len(thing):
                result.append(thing[i:j])
    return result

res = parts([*range(1,11)])
# res
# [[1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5],
# [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
# [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [3, 4], [3, 4, 5],
# [3, 4, 5, 6], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
# [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [4, 5], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6, 7], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
# [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [5, 6], [5, 6, 7], [5, 6, 7, 8],
# [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [6, 7], [6, 7, 8], [6, 7, 8, 9],
# [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [7, 8], [7, 8, 9], [7, 8, 9, 10], [8, 9], [8, 9, 10],
# [9, 10]]
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. please use a list like [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] and show what you have. Please include all code that yields your result.

Comment: @DanielJames on SO, it is a privilege to receive an answer, and a privilege to ask.

Comment: It finds every substring of length 2 or greater that leave at least one fragment of at least length 1. In other words, it finds all viable substrings without enumerating every partition. In other words, every substring where `1 < len(substring) < len(thing)` can appear in the partition you have described.

Comment: I expected it to take float and integer and not string.

Comment: "string" is a generic term for an ordered list of things, as well as a description of the data type that we use for character strings. Just look at the original code. Create an array and see what `range(len(your_array))` gets you. Do the same with `your_array[2:5]`, for example. Modify the method above to print the indices, instead of appending to `result`. You're not trying. You're going to be miserable until you start trying, and learning some basic techniques for investigating your own issues. Until then, you're going to feel lost and put-upon, and be a nuisance to others.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I am grateful.